# Is there a Visual Studio Plug-In to Sync open tabs across multiple machines?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, ide, tabs, synchronization

I often work on a solution in Visual Studio at work, commit my changes to version control, and pull the changes at home to work on using my home machine with Visual Studio.  It would be nice if there was a way that I could restore the session that I checked in (maybe some session file that could be version controlled) to automatically open all of the same tabs on my home machine I had open when I checked in at work (and vice versa).  I think the current session is stored in the .suo file, which I have read is bad practice to version control as it is specific to an individual machine environment, so I'm not sure that is the way to go, or if it would work properly.

I find myself having to close a lot of tabs when I open a solution and then having to mentally go through the process of remembering what I was last working on and re-opening those tabs, so something like this would allow me to avoid that and get right to work.

Preferably, this would work with any tab, not just project files.  For example, ReSharper test runner tabs, NCrunch tabs, Object Browser Tab, etc.

Anyone know of anything like this or have a simple work-around?

Thanks

Comment: hi...i think..u have to just commit the code which u modified in repository...so, it will be not open all tabs...it's should have own session...

Comment: As you pointed out, the suo file contains this information, so could you sync this file using another tool like SkyDrive or Dropbox?

Comment: Syncing the .suo does not work correctly if your paths are not exactly the same on both machines.  E.g. one machine working on D:\ and another C:\, it doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

You should put your source code under a cloud based synchronization tool.

For example, I put my projects in my skydrive folder (sync by the official skydrive tool). This will automatically synchronize all files, including the .suo file, and temp files.

This is not mutually exclusive with source code control. The repository (git in my case), will also be synchronized between computers. And then, only legitimate files will go under source control (the .suo is synchronized only between *your* computers, but won't go into *shared* source repository)

Comment: I've tried this approach before and ran into problems specifically with the .suo files no working properly between instances.  It's been awhile, but I think it had to do with filesystem paths not matching, and maybe other so other problems too.  I agree with you in general that maybe the sync info would not go into source control be would be synced, I just don't think relying on .suo will work, at least it hasn't for me.